# How to Install JSONNET tools on Windows-10?

Tags: windows, installation, jsonnet

I need to use this library since its a project requirements.

I am referring to official release website : https://jsonnet.org/learning/tools.html

But sadly no way find out for installation on Windows.

Need help for this topic.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find multi-arch `jsonnet` CLI releases at https://github.com/google/go-jsonnet/releases, in particular as of now:

```
go-jsonnet_0.18.0_Windows_armv6.tar.gz
go-jsonnet_0.18.0_Windows_i386.tar.gz
go-jsonnet_0.18.0_Windows_x86_64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

It's available in Scoop.

Run: scoop install go-jsonnet